# How to make FieldGroup type: file multiple react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to upload multiple files in react component.
I don't see any example for this.
Can I do it?
or any alternatives?

```
<Col sm={12} md={12}>
                <FieldGroup
                  id='formControlsFile'
                  type='file'
                  label='File'
                  multiple
                />
</Col>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQZEEM) is allowing multiple files.

Example code below

```
<FormControl id="formControlsFile"
      type="file"
         multiple
      label="File" />
```

In your example, looks like you have a wrapper component FormGroup which should take multiple in its prop.

Comment: Thanks but your example does not upload multiple files when i upload another it deletes the previous file's name and puts the new file's name

Comment: Selecting multiple files is giving that 2 files are selected. Am I assuming your comment wrong?

Comment: I am sorry I was choosing two file but each time one file.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool. Happy that the answer helped you